# How to get MobX Decorators to work with Create-React-App v2?

Tags: reactjs, decorator, babeljs, create-react-app, mobx

> Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled

I tried adding the `decorators-legacy` babel plugin and `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` with `{ legacy: true }` in `.babelrc` but no effect.

Anyone managed to get MobX decorators to work with CRA2?

Comment: Is your project a monorepo which contains both the native-web and react-native app?

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, install dependencies:

`yarn add react-app-rewired customize-cra @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators`

Secondly, create `config-overrides.js` in root directory with following contents:

```
const {
    addDecoratorsLegacy,
    override,
    disableEsLint
} = require("customize-cra");

module.exports = {
    webpack: override(
        addDecoratorsLegacy(),
        disableEsLint()
    )
};
```

You should be able to use mobx + decorators now.

*If you don't have mobx installed already, please run:
`yarn add mobx mobx-react`.
Now you can use decorators.*

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue and ended up with using mobx4 where **Decorators can be used without decorator syntax**.

```
class Store {
  //...
  @action empty() {
    this.data = []
  }

  @action add(e) {
    this.data.push(e)
  }
}
```

can be rewritten as

```
class Store {
      //...
       empty() {
        this.data = []
      }

      add(e) {
        this.data.push(e)
      }
    }

decorate(Store, {
  add: action,
  empty: action
})
```

You can use this feature out of the box from CRA2 and do not need to worry about transform decoracy plugin. Thanks Michel Weststrate  for this stuff

https://medium.com/@mweststrate/mobx-4-better-simpler-faster-smaller-c1fbc08008da

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1: Using decorators with CRA v2**

If you refer to [Mobx documentation](https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html), you can get Mobx decorators to work with CRAv2 by using [Typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript):

> Decorators are only supported out of the box when using TypeScript in create-react-app@^2.1.1.

However, in some cases, you might still face issues when using Mobx with other react frameworks. In that case:

**Option 2: Don't use decorators**

A detailed step by step guide is documented [here](https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html).

If you previously defined your observer react component as:

```
@observer
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component
```

Change it to:

```
const MyComponent = observer(class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  /* ... */
});

export default MyComponent;
```

If you previously had:

```
@observable myElement = null;
```

You need to change it to:

```
myElement;
```

then:

```
decorate(MyComponent, {
  myElement: observable,
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: option 2 works and also makes it look more legible!

Answer (score 3):

I did an [example project](https://github.com/almog-kiki/react-mobx-page-animation) of React App 2.0 with Babel 7 and Mobx(with decorators works) without eject! :

Links I used to create this project:

https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/issues/348

https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra#addbabelpluginsplugins

https://www.leighhalliday.com/mobx-create-react-app-without-ejecting

Comment: Finally someone posted a working example! I've lost quite some time with it before, thanks a bunch!

Comment: You have a constant typo here and in your repo. It's BABEL, not BABLE.

Answer (score 2):

If you use babel 7 you have to add some config in babelrc. Install support for decorators:

> npm i --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators

And enable it in your .babelrc file:

```
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true}],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true}]
    ]
}
```

or you can use MobX built-in utility like:

```
import { observable, computed, action, decorate } from "mobx";

class Timer {
  start = Date.now();
  current = Date.now();

  get elapsedTime() {
    return this.current - this.start + "milliseconds";
  }

  tick() {
    this.current = Date.now();
  }
}
decorate(Timer, {
  start: observable,
  current: observable,
  elapsedTime: computed,
  tick: action
});
```

I had the same problem and I used mobx-utility and every thing completely worked for me.

Comment: The block of code under "plugins" is the only thing that helped in my case (reactnative 0.61.5). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don’t have to use more packages, or change configurations.

1-  Use decorate in stores – for observable, computed :

```
import { observable, decorate } from "mobx"

class ToDoStore {
    todos= ["cat","dog"]
}
decorate(ToDoStore, {
    todos: observable,
  });

const store = new ToDoStore()
```

2-  For observer – use the follow class style:

```
import React from "react"
import { observer } from "mobx-react"

const TodoList = observer(class TodoList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {todos} = this.props.store;
        const todoL = todos.map(todo => (<li>{todo}</li>))
        return (
            <div>
            <h1>ToDo List</h1>
            <ul>{todoL}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
})
export default TodoList
```

Answer (score 1):

While using CRA2, in order to use MOBX5 you must do following.

```
npm install -save mobx mobx-react
```

Now add following lines in your store file.

```
import {decorate, observable} from "mobx"
import {observer} from "mobx-react"
```

Now you can use something like this.

```
class Store {
  //...
}

decorate(Store, {
  list: observable
})

const appStore = new Store()`
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to find a proper tutorial for this other than the MobX 4 blog post that mentions it. Do you know of any good resources? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

although others answers are correct if you want to avoid boilerplate code, It's possible to use decorators in CRA2 without ejecting using https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/ and https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra

Answer (score -1):

npm run eject

Add the bold line to /config/webpack.config.dev.js around line 162. Make sure to do the same on /config/webpack.config.prod.js otherwise the app won’t build

plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],